# Mix of jquery and a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to submit a form to the php (that will send it to mysql database), the problem is that i'm beeing able to submit the text description and text content, but the category and sub category is selected by a script and i'm not beeing able to access to them.
I'm passing my code. I'm new to jquery and php. I spent a lot of hours trying to solve it without success. Thanks in advance.

```
     <?php require_once ('../../includes/select.php');?>
     <?php
     if (!$_POST['descricao'] == "") {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO conteudos(descricao,conteudo,categorias_id,subcategorias_id)                        VALUES('" . $_POST['descricao'] ."','" .$_POST['conteudo'] ."','" . $_POST['categoria']  ."','" . $_POST['subcategoria'] ."');";
 $sqlconf = mysql_query($sql);
 if (!empty($sqlconf)){
    $message = "O novo conteudo foi criado com sucesso.";
}
else {
    $message = "Erro na criação do conteudo, tente novamente.";
}
    }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

        $("select#subcategoria").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#categoria").change(function(){
        $("select#subcategoria").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#subcategoria").html("<option>aguarde...</option>");
        var id = $("select#categoria option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("selec_subcategoria.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#subcategoria").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#subcategoria").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("#seleciona").submit(function(){
        var desc = $("#descricao").text();
        var cont = $("#conteudo").text();
        var cat = $("select#categoria option:selected").attr('value');
        var subcat = $("select#subcategoria option:selected").attr('value');
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#result").html('');
        //var values = $(this).serialize();
        if(cat>0 && subcat>0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?pagina=gere_conteudos.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#seleciona").serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                    $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
                }
            });
            /*$.post('index.php?pagina=gere_conteudos.php', { descricao: desc});
            $.post('index.php?pagina=gere_conteudos.php', { conteudo: cont});
            $.post('index.php?pagina=gere_conteudos.php', { categoria: cat});
            $.post('index.php?pagina=gere_conteudos.php', { subcategoria: subcat});
            //$("#result").html('A sua escolha: '+result);*/
            $("#teste").html(desc);
            $("#teste2").html(cont);
        }
        else
        {   

            $("#result").html("Tem de escolher todas as opções disponiveis!");

        }
        //return false;
    });
});
       </script>

    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">SIB - Gestão de conteudos</a></h2>
    <p class="meta">Domingo, Dezembro 03, 2013 7:27 AM Posted by <a href="#">Someone</a></p>
    <div class="entry">

<div class="tabelas" >
    <p>Aqui deverá criar e gerir as publicações de conteudos para o seu sistema de informação de balcões. Só após a criação das categorias é que poderá criar as publicações de conteudos.</p>


    <?php if (!empty($message)) {
        echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";
    }
    ?>
    <form id="seleciona">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Descrição para a publicação a criar:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="descricao" name="descricao" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($descricao); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto da publicação:</td>
                <td>
                  <textarea id="conteudo" name="conteudo" rows="15" cols="55" ="<?php echo htmlentities($conteudo); ?>"> </textarea></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Escolha de categoria:</td>
                <td>
                <select id="categoria">
                <?php print $opt->ShowCategoria(); ?>
                </select>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Escolha de subcategoria:</td>
                <td>
                <select id="subcategoria">
                    <option value="0">Escolha...</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Criar conteudo" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="teste"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the dynamic values; you forgot to put a `name` attribute so they are not included when you serialize the form using `data: $("#seleciona").serialize(),`.

Change:

```
<select id="categoria">
```

to:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
```

and:

```
<select id="subcategoria">
```

to:

```
<select id="subcategoria" name="subcategoria">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only form elements with a `name` attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.  You need to add  `name` attribute in your input elements.